# What is the Equivalent of SetResourceReference in a Metro Application?

Tags: wpf, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm attempting to set a reference to a style in a control I'm creating in the code behind. Normally in WPF, I'd use the SetResourceReference method. However, I see that this method doesn't seem to exist on the Button property in Metro.

What is the equivalent in a Metro application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended using a [custom implementation of TryFindResource shown here](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2011/01/findresource-implementation-for.html). The problem with using the this.Resources property suggested in a different answer is that it doesn't search up the entire resource tree for resources that might be in the App resources. The implementation in the link I provided does that. It is based off of something common in Silverlight which has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

WinRT, like Silverlight, doesn't have that technique (it's missing "DynamicResource" markup extension and the support that goes with it).

You could try one of the following:

- Set the [style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.style.aspx) property
- Set the [template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.template.aspx) property

To set the Style for example, you can do something like this.

With [Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.resources.aspx):

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="boldButton">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    </Style>               
</Page.Resources>
```

and a button:

```
<Button Name="btn" Content="Button" />
```

In the code behind:

```
btn.Style = this.Resources["boldButton"] as Style;
```

Comment: That doesn't really give me enough, since my Style is defined in XAML, and there doesn't seem to be a FindResource method either! How am I supposed to actually get a Style object?

Comment: Added a simple example of setting Style using the Resources property of a Page, retrieving a resource by key, and then assigning it to a button instance.

Comment: I ended up using a custom implementation of TryFindResource which I documented in a different answer. I gave you a +1 for the additional help though. :)